# Significant parameters for a 2-D Affine transformation in Photogrammetry

Tags: matrix, coordinate-transformation, affinetransform, photogrammetry

In the context of photogrammetry, if you are given the parameters for a 2-D Affine transformation, how would you determine which parameters are significant?

My intuition suggests that you would compare your output to your control data, tie in points etc. Perhaps compare different outputs using different input values for each parameter to determine how they affect the outcome. Perhaps there is a statistical test? I'm just not sure how to demonstrate this clearly (or if this is even the right  option)